# Remapping the path of Java resources in Gradle

Tags: angular, spring-boot, gradle

I need to build a single `war` file containing both a Spring Boot backend and an Angular frontend, coming from different repositories.

The idea is that Azure DevOps builds the Angular app in a pipeline, and the Spring Boot pipe fetches the Angular artifact to include under `/static` resources directory.

I'm currently experimenting locally to create the proper Gradle code.

I have a copy of `my-app`, which is the directory Angular creates under `dist` after `ng build`, and I will be pasting it under the backend's repository root, at same level to `build.gradle`

I need to tell Gradle that, if the directory exists, its content **must be mapped** into `static` directory under resources

```
def frontEndDirectory = file('my-app')

if (frontEndDirectory.isDirectory()) {
    project.sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDir frontEndDirectory
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This copies the resources directly under the war file's `WEB-INF/classes`, but they should be under `WEB-INF/classes/static`

**I would like to ask** how to easily tell Gradle to pick files from a certain directory and drop them into `/static` subdirectory of the resources.

Today I got my Angular application as a directory, but it is particularly likely that I will need to get it from a zip file in DevOps. That is going to be my next step.

#### I also tried

Creating a CopyTask script

```
if (frontEndDirectory.isDirectory()) {
    task copyGeneratedFiles(type: Copy) {
        from frontEndDirectory
        into 'build/resources/main/static'
    }
    tasks.war.dependsOn(copyGeneratedFiles)
}
```

This has the **desired** result of copying the files in the correct place in the staging directory (`build/resources/main/static`), but the files do not appear in the final war file

Comment: Can you try a different task dependency? I would suggest to have `processResources` depend on `copyGeneratedFiles` (as these are resources).  

You can also try to configure the processResources task directly (which is a copy task), e.g.  

```
processResources {
    from("my-webapp") {
        into("static")
    }
}

Comment: And the winner is.... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @atomfrede comment, the following worked

```
if (frontEndDirectory.isDirectory()) {
    task copyGeneratedFiles(type: Copy) {
        from frontEndDirectory
        into 'build/resources/main/static'
    }
    tasks.processResources.dependsOn(copyGeneratedFiles)
}
```

The custom task had to run before the `processResources` task